# submitHandler keeps reloading page

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to send a form to a php file once submitted and retrieve the value without reloading the page. It has been working great for a while but now I can't get it to work. I have multiple pages doing a similar task and 2 work really well but the other 3 don't...

I have been going through the code over and over but I can't find the issue. I also noticed when I click submit, the values I entered into the form just go into the adress bar of my browser and the page reloads not even going to the php file.

Here is the JS:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                    $("#myform").validate({

                        submitHandler: function(form) {
                            // do other stuff for a valid form
                            $.post('process.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
                                $('.results').html(data).show(); // you can chain for efficiency

                            });

                        }
                    });
                });
        </script>
```

AND THE HTML SORRY FOR THE LENGTH:

```
    <form id = 'myform'>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>College GPA Calculator</legend>
                    <div class = 'btn-container'>
                        <button class = "btn btn-info" type = 'button'id = "add">Add Row </button>
                        <button class = "btn btn-info" type = 'button'id = "remove"> Remove Row</button>
                    </div>
<table>

                        <tr> 
                            <th> Class Name </th> <th> Units </th> <th> GPA </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> <input class = 'input-medium'type = 'text' placeholder = "Optional"> </td> 
                            <td> <input class = 'input-small'type = "text" name = "units[]" placeholder = "Units Earned"> </td>
                            <td> 
                                <select class = 'selectpicker' name = "grades[]" >
                                    <option value = "0"> SELECT </option>
                                    <option value = "A"> A </option>
                                    <option value = "AMINUS"> A- </option>
                                    <option value = "BPLUS"> B+ </option>
                                    <option value = "B"> B </option>
                                    <option value = "BMINUS"> B- </option>
                                    <option value = "CPLUS"> C+</option>
                                    <option value = "C"> C </option>
                                    <option value = "CMINUS"> C- </option>
                                    <option value = "DPLUS"> D+ </option>
                                    <option value = "D"> D </option>
                                    <option value = "DMINUS"> D- </option>
                                    <option value = "F"> F</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> <input class = 'input-medium'type = 'text' placeholder = "Optional"> </td> 
                            <td> <input class = 'input-small'type = "text" name = "units[]" placeholder = "Units Earned"> </td>
                            <td> 
                                <select class = 'selectpicker' name = "grades[]" >
                                        <option value = "0"> SELECT </option>
                                    <option value = "A"> A </option>
                                    <option value = "AMINUS"> A- </option>
                                    <option value = "BPLUS"> B+ </option>
                                    <option value = "B"> B </option>
                                    <option value = "BMINUS"> B- </option>
                                    <option value = "CPLUS"> C+</option>
                                    <option value = "C"> C </option>
                                    <option value = "CMINUS"> C- </option>
                                    <option value = "DPLUS"> D+ </option>
                                    <option value = "D"> D </option>
                                    <option value = "DMINUS"> D- </option>
                                    <option value = "F"> F</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>



                    </table>
                    <div class = 'bottomCalcResults'>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        <button class = 'btn btn-warning' id = 'reset'type = 'reset'>Reset</button>
                        <div class = 'results'></div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

HERE ARE THE INSTALL SCRIPTS:

```
<link rel = 'stylesheet' type = 'text/css' href = 'assets/css/style.css' media = "screen">
        <link rel= 'stylesheet' type = 'text/css' href = 'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'>    
        <link rel = 'stylesheet' type = 'text/css' href = 'assets/css/normalize.css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src = "assets/js/dropdown.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

I don't know what is going on but I can't seem to find it! Please help!
Thanks.

Comment: Your code works for me. Are you including jquery and the validate plugin in your html file?

Comment: I just added it in an edit. I don't know whats happening at all if it works for you... Frustration level: high

Comment: look in browser console for errors thrown. You must prevent browser default in submit handler but from comment below when you did it still submitted, which means must be error thrown in console. Don't hot link to github, use CDN instead

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `return false` as the last item inside of the plugin's `submitHandler` callback function.  If the page is still reloading after you've added `return false`, you haven't added it properly.

This is where to place `return false;`:

```
$(function () {
    $("#myform").validate({
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $.post('process.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function (data) {
                $('.results').html(data).show();
            });
            return false; // <- last item inside submitHandler function
        }
    });
});
```

**Working Demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/2QspF/

The only difference between jsFiddle demo and your real code is that the `$.post` function is commented out to prevent a jsFiddle 404 error because we don't have access to your `process.php` file.

**Side-note**:  You should also be able to use `$(form).serialize()` in place of `$("#myform").serialize()`.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/L7vLt/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
return false;
```

from your submitHandler function.  I *think* that since you're posting the form via ajax that you will need to prevent the default functionality from happening

Comment: Ok - possibly need to add an event.stopImmediatePropagation - or something similar

Comment: No, a `return false` is the correct way to stop the form `submit` when using `ajax` inside the jQuery Validation plugin's `submitHandler` callback function.